# I can't assign an IP address to vmware VM from DHCP pool

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, router, dhcp

In GNS3, I have configured the DHCP pool on the router R1, and I have a vmware VM (Ubuntu 16.04), another router R2 and VPCs are connected to R1. The R2 and VPC can get their IP address without a problem, however, the vmwareVM can't receive the IP address.

Note that:

- the station is configured as host-only
- the connect a host virtual adapter to this network is checked
- the VMware Workstation DHCP Server is turned OFF
- No configuration on my local PC Network Connections (DHCP)

Once I type the command dhclient eth0 to get the IP address from dhcp, it freezes and returns nothing and no IP address is assigned.

I want to know what is the problem that causes that issue and how to solve it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was in the configuration of my VMware network adapter (VMnet2) in my network adapter in my host.
so in order to get the IP address from the DHCP router: I did the following steps:

1. Create a virtual network (VMnet2) in the virtual network editor
   of VMware.
2. I checked the "Host-only" option
3. I checked the
   "connect a host virtual adapter to this network" option
4. Uncheck the "use local DHCP service to distribute IP address to VMs".
5. Do not change the default configuration of the VMnet from your
   network connexion options.

I hope that will help someone has the same issue as me